# Perl mail attachment file size limit

Tags: perl, email

I am using MIME::Lite module to send attachments in email and everything works fine until I realized attachment larger than 15mb cannot be sent successfully. Any suggestion on other module which not having size limit?

Comment: You don't provide the exact error you received. Why do you think MIME:Lite has a size limit? Check that your mail server and the recipient mail server both accept messages that are that size.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using a different module because that's what [the author recommends](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#WAIT!) (try `Email::MIME`, `MIME::Entity` or `Email::Sender`). However, it's not the module that determines the attachment size restriction.

The size limit you're seeing is set by your SMTP server. If you're not explicitly configuring your SMTP server you're using your local service which might differ depending on your OS. You're probably using `sendmail` or `postfix`.

**See size limit in postfix**

```sh
postconf | grep message_size_limit
```

**See size limit in sendmail**

```sh
grep MaxMessageSize /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

If you're using an external SMTP server they usually have their own size limits. Google has a 25MB size limit for their SMTP server `smtp.gmail.com`. If that's sufficient for you you could send your mail via Google by authenticating.

```perl
$msg->send(
    'smtp', 'smtp.gmail.com',
    Port     => 465,
    SSL      => 1,
    AuthUser => $user,
    AuthPass => $password,
);
```

---

**EDIT**: I had some issues using `MIME::Lite` to work properly with Gmail SMTP server so I here's an example on how to use `gmail.smtp.com` with an alternative pacakge.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw( sendmail );
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP;
use Email::Simple;

my $user     = 'username@gmail.com';
my $password = 'app-password';
my $host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
my $port     = 465;

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new(
    {
        host          => $host,
        port          => $port,
        ssl           => 1,
        sasl_username => $user,
        sasl_password => $password,
    }
);

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        To      => 'someone@example.com',
        From    => 'me@localhost',
        Subject => 'Hello...',
    ],
    body => "World!\n",
);

sendmail( $email, { transport => $transport } );
```